# Angular 2 Service value not persisting

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service which I have created to handle getting a user and checking their permissions. When I use it in my app, the value I want to persist across the app appears to reset back to what it was every time I call a `getUser()` method.

My service code is thus:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyHttp } from '../my-http/my-http.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { MyAuth } from '../my-auth.service';
import { MyAuthUser } from './my-auth-user.ts';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyUserService {
    private currUser: MyAuthUser = {
        id: 'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER',
        name:'Anonymous',
        roles: []
    };

    constructor(private http: MyHttp, private auth: MyAuth) {}

    public extractData(res: Response): MyAuthUser {
        let user = res.json();
        this.currUser = Object.assign({}, user)
        return this.currUser;
    }

    public getUser(): Observable<MyAuthUser> {
        // Check if we already have user
        if(this.currUser.id === 'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER') {
            // Get user from tokeninfo endpoint
            return this.http.get('/myuserendpoint')
                .map(this.extractData);
        }
        else {
            // Either user is unauthenticated or user already exists, either way send back whatever is in this.currUser
            return Observable.create((observer:any) => {
                observer.next(this.currUser);
                observer.complete();
            });
        }
    }

    public hasRole(role: string): boolean {
        if(!this.currUser || this.currUser.id === 'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER') {
            throw new Error('User roles is undefined, make sure you call getUser');
        }

        return !!~this.currUser.roles.indexOf(role);
    }
}
```

I'm adding it as a provider in my app's bootstrap method:

```
bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [MyUser, ...]);
```

Then I am using it in my root component to get the user and check whether they have a specific role:

```
constructor(private userService: MyUser) {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        let isDeveloper = this.userService.hasRole('developer');
        console.log('IS DEV?: ', isDeveloper);
    });
}
```

So the user comes back successfully and is set to `this.user`, however when I run the `hasRole()` method which should just check against the service's `currUser` value, it is somehow reset to the `UNAUTHENTICATED_USER` again. I can't figure out why this value is not persisting from one method call to the next.

I'm not super well versed in observables, so I can't tell if maybe something I'm doing there is messing with it or what.

Comment: Where exactly is the code line where `currUser` returns `UNAUTHENTICATED_USER`?

Comment: The issue is that when the `if` statement is run in `hasRole()`, `this.currUser.id` is equal to `UNAUTHENTICATED_USER` again, despite having just been set as the user I received back from my http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing method references this way causes troubles if the passed method refers to `this´

```
.map(this.extractData);
```

Use instead

```
.map(() => this.extractData())
```

or if it needs to accept a parameter

```
.map((x) => this.extractData(x))
```

This way the scope of `this` is retained.

Comment: Oh that's right, thanks so much! I completely missed that, thanks so much for the answer!